# How to check user entered date is greater than 32 days from current date in java

Tags: java, validation, date, conditional-statements, jodatime

I would like to validate the date input of the user based on a condition. The condition is new date entered by user should be greater than 32 days. How to do the same?. I have tried the following but it is not working.

```
final Date getuserDate = validate.date();
logger.debug("UserDate is" + getuserDate);
DateTime currentExpdelDate = new DateTime(getuserDate);
DateTime currentDate = new DateTime();

DateTime dtPlus = currentDate.plusDays(32);
long millisec = dtPlus.getMillis() - currentExpdelDate.getMillis();
if (millisec > 0) {
    long diffDays = millisec / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    if (diffDays < 32) {

        System.out.println("Date should be greater than 32 days")
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. org.joda.time.DateTime;

Comment: Okay Apologies . If we can manage with Java standard libraries, please suggest the way to do the same

Comment: Oh, the Java `Date` class is truly rubbish and `Calendar` and its associated classes aren't much better. If you're already using Joda time, you're probably ahead of the game. I haven't had the pleasure, but people talk it up.

Comment: *"but it is not working"* ... and how is it not working? Do you get an exception? Is the result wrong? Do you get a compiler error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The universal type `DateTime` is not suitable for a date-only task. You should therefore choose the type `LocalDate` in the Joda-Time-library.

Then you can use this [constructor](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#LocalDate-java.lang.Object-org.joda.time.DateTimeZone-). Note that you need to specify the timezone because the current date is not the same date all around in the world at the same time.

```
java.util.Date input = ...;
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID(...);

LocalDate userDate = new LocalDate(input, zone);
boolean exclude = new LocalDate(zone).plusDays(32).isAfter(userDate);

if (exclude) {
  System.out.println("Date should be greater than 32 days in the future.");
}
```

Comment: How to give timezone for Indian standard time

Comment: Will it check the date entered by user is greater than 32 days from current date ??

Comment: @KathirvelAppusamy About India Time: Just use `DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Kolkata")`. You can also leave it out completely if this is your system timezone although I consider this approach as potentially dangerous because your program might be running on a US-located server for example..

Answer (score 1):

If you are already on **Java 8** you can use its new new [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class using [`plusDays()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#plusDays-long-) and [`isBefore()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#isBefore-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate-) methods.